# What is the equivalent to SoapExtension for JSON WebMethods?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've a few web methods that I use to call some external services like the Google Calendar API, obviously these can be extremely brittle.

Unfortunately I now realise that any error thrown on these methods are not causing an exception to bubble up to Global.asax which is where errors are getting logged in this application.

I have seen suggestions to wrap the method in a try/catch, which is a stupid way of doing it as there are a variety of errors that ASP.Net will silently swallow still.

In trying to find a solution I've seen a lot of references to `SoapExtension`, which is exactly what I want to do but doesn't get fired as I'm returning Json. What I really want is a way to catch the error just like that.

Any pointers appreciated, I still can't understand how the ASP.Net team could have thought that silently swallowing errors like this was a bright idea.

So for example a method like this:

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ExceptionHandling] //can I write a handler like this to catch exceptions from JSON webservices?
    static public void DeleteItem(string id)
    {
        var api = new GoogleCalendarAPI(User.InternalUser());
        api.DeleteEvent(id);
        return "success";
    }
```

Comment: Your problem is that you're using a legacy technology when you should be using WCF. WCF is _much_ more extensible than ASMX.

Comment: @JohnSaunders WCF is terrible and will be as dead as a dodo in a few years, it's legacy itself. If I could be using anything I'd go for MVC, but alas you can't rewrite a client's legacy project overnight

Comment: An exception handler can only catch exceptions. If the exceptions are being hidden, then are no exceptions to handle.

Comment: MVC is completely different from WCF. MVC is about separating data from presentation. WCF is about sending data between endpoints.

Comment: @JohnSaunders The problem with Microsoft technologies is that they are never backward compatible. If you have to mantain an old project with asp.net 2.0 using asmx, you should migrate to wcf just to log errors: this is a nightmare.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no equivalent to `SoapExtension` for JSON WebMethods and having custom errors turned on in your production site will result in a generic error message being returned to the client, no error is ever raised on the server. You cannot circumvent this.

If you inspect the code using something like ILSpy, there is no way to pass a method or class to page WebMethods like `SoapExtension`. The error is swallowed by ASP.Net as it invokes the web method, the only notification you will get is a HTTP 500 error sent to the client with a total generic error message.

In 4.0, WebMethods get called by this:

```
// System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler
internal static void ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)
{
    try
    {
        //snip irrelevant code
        RestHandler.InvokeMethod(context, methodData, rawParams);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        RestHandler.WriteExceptionJsonString(context, ex);
    }
}
```

So if invoking your method throws an error it will call the following code with a statusCode of 500, there's no re-throw in there and nothing else you can pass in called so unless I'm being blind it just gets swallowed silently. Even worse if you've got custom errors turned on, which any sane person will, it'll completely obfuscate the original cause:

```
// System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler
internal static void WriteExceptionJsonString(HttpContext context, Exception ex, int statusCode)
{
    //snip code setting up response
    context.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
    using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(context.Response.OutputStream, new UTF8Encoding(false)))
    {
        if (ex is TargetInvocationException)
        {
            ex = ex.InnerException;
        }
        if (context.IsCustomErrorEnabled)
        {
            streamWriter.Write(JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeInternal(RestHandler.BuildWebServiceError(AtlasWeb.WebService_Error, string.Empty, string.Empty)));
        }
        else
        {
            streamWriter.Write(JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeInternal(RestHandler.BuildWebServiceError(ex.Message, ex.StackTrace, ex.GetType().FullName)));
        }
        streamWriter.Flush();
    }
}
```

I can't see a way around it, looks like WebMethod is not ready for production code, shame.

Answer (score 0):

It's not so much they get disappeared, it's more that they get passed out to the calling client. Since however you don't always want to (or should) reveal such intimate details of your service, you can prevent errors bubbling out of your service. This gives the impression of them disappearing.

Wrapping the inner detail in a try-catch is about the best way to cope with any errors. Within the method you're dealing with standard error trapping. So I think you'd want something like:

```
[WebMethod]
static public string DeleteItem(string id)
{
    try
    {
        var api = new GoogleCalendarAPI(User.InternalUser());
        api.DeleteEvent(id);
        return "success";
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        log.fatal(ex);
        return "error";
    }
}
```

If anything throws an exception within the try-catch it'll be caught. ASP.Net won't interfere with it, unless the methods you are calling have been specifically coded to do so.

**Edit**

If the GoogleCalendarAPI class is in turn calling a method, such as ExecuteWebServiceCall with catches the Exception, then you'd have to parse the response. I'd hope they gave you some other clue, like a response code, to indicate an error state. You could then wrap that in an Exception, throw it have it caught by your default error handler.

Comment: I specifically said I didn't want to do this. There are lots of ways this will fail to catch a serious error on a WebMethod. What about when a DateTime param errors due to the wrong format because your js calendar control is misconfigured? Or an integer overflow happens? Or the user passes an ' asp.net forbidden' character in the response? This will catch none of those. It's a terrible solution.

Comment: They will all be caught be the exception handler. Why do you not think they will be caught? From your examples, DateTime parse will throw a FormatException, which will be caught. The int will throw an overflowException which is caught. If the code throws an exception then it will be caught. ASP.net can't interfere with it at this stage because it doesn't know the exception has occurred yet. It won't know the exception has occurred until the exception is passed out of the method.

Comment: How does it interfere? An Exception bubbles up the call stack until it's handled. Asp.net is bound by the same rules of exception handling as the rest of the framework. I think we're talking about different things here. My answer isn't stupid, it's just not what you wanted, given that what you've shown that Exceptions are trapped so you need an alternative to Exception handling.

Comment: I stand by the d/v. You've not been clear what you're trying to do, not given me a chance to explain or clarify and I believe you're answer is not useful as it's not clear how this relates to your question.

Comment: In the question I specifically said I couldn't use a try...catch and that's what you suggested, what extra clarification did you need? Your answer was annoying because you didn't even bother to read the question. And seriously, your 'trapped' exceptions sound suspiciously like my 'silently swallowed' ones don't they? Next time ask for clarification in the comments.

Comment: Ok, so I shouldn't have made such a point of try-catch but my reading of your question was you were wrong in your assertion that the Exceptions were disappearing. The point I was making, badly i'll agree, is that Exception do not disappear. They are caught. ASP cannot interfere with them. I've modified my answer to better explain my point.