# Server returns 500 code but can't trap error

Tags: asp.net, .net, xml, web-services, iis

I have an ASP.NET web service running in IIS, on a Windows 2003 server.

Here are the IIS logs for a call I had done using another .NET program.  It correctly responded to my application with "Hello World"

```
2013-03-25 19:38:36 W3SVC1406312275 VMC-MMS 192.168.1.223 POST /test.asmx wsdl/mex 80 - 172.16.129.193 HTTP/1.1 - - - webservices.vm.vmc 500 0 0 775 677 1671
2013-03-25 19:38:36 W3SVC1406312275 VMC-MMS 192.168.1.223 GET /test.asmx wsdl 80 - 172.16.129.193 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+MS+Web+Services+Client+Protocol+2.0.50727.5466) - - webservices.vm.vmc 200 0 0 3103 183 2531
2013-03-25 19:38:36 W3SVC1406312275 VMC-MMS 192.168.1.223 POST /test.asmx wsdl 80 - 172.16.129.193 HTTP/1.1 - - - webservices.vm.vmc 500 0 0 775 645 250
```

Here is the IIS log for a call done from an RPG program... which is sending back "500" "Internal Server Error"

```
2013-03-25 21:10:26 W3SVC1406312275 VMC-MMS 192.168.1.223 POST /test.asmx - 80 - 192.168.1.6 HTTP/1.1 http-api/1.24 - - webservices.vm.vmc 500 0 0 697 32968 2421
```

### ------------------

### ------------------

My Global.asax Application_Start and Application_Error are both coded to log a message when they are hit.

Calls from both .NET and RPG write to the log file in the Application_Start function... but neither writes to the log in the Application_Error function.

HelloWorld only initializes a logger and returns the string "Hello World".  And... the log is getting written in both calls.

**So... how do I trap whatever error is occurring?** which is sending back the 500 code.

Comment: I see you're using WSDL with ASMX files - are you using a web-services framework on top of ASP.NET?

Comment: Yes we are running IIS with .NET Framework 2.0

Comment: I can see that, but is your application using WCF or some other framework **on top** of ASP.NET?

Comment: Did you check the Event Viewer to see if any ASP.NET errors are getting logged there?

Comment: @Dai I just go to Add New Item -> Web Service.  Not WCF Service or any other option.  Sorry if i'm still missing the question.

Comment: @rsbarro I see various things in System... but the particular error about "Duplicate name on the TCP network" has been happening before my tests.  Inside Application there are a few errors, but nothing since noon and I've been testing a lot since then... so I guess.... no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `Application_Error` does not fire for unhandled exceptions in web services.

Check the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211530/why-global-asax-application-error-method-does-not-catch-exceptions-thrown-by-asm) for more information. You're going to have to do something like either add a try-catch to each web method, or create a SOAP extension to handle the web service exceptions.

I would probably go the SOAP extension route and create an extension I could use in all my projects as a generic web service exception handler.

**UPDATE**
One of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180228/handle-exceptions-in-web-services-with-elmah) has a SOAP extension code example.